# Не удается подключиться к серверу со статическим IP

Tags: c#, сеть, сокет, socket.io

Приветсвтую.
Написал на c# простое приложение клиент-сервер. На 127.0.0.1 работает как нужно. Когда я переношу сервер на машину со статическим IP-адресом (194.87.235.148), то клиенту не удается подключиться к серверу. 
Вот так слушю на сервере:

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(35000);
tcpListener.Start();
```

Вот так подключается клиент:

```
client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("194.87.235.148", 35000);
```

В итоге вылаетает такое сообщение:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 194.87.235.148:35000

Пробовал слушать по разным портам - не помогло.
Если на сервере запустить и клиентское и серверное приложение, то тоже все нормально работает.
Может надо как-то по особому сервер настроить или еще что? 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Документация говорит, что конструктор TcpListener(Int32) устарел, замените его на другой для начала

Comment: Пробовал через IPEndPoint тоже не помогло. Я все больше начинаю склоняться к тому, что какие-то проблемы на сервере в целом. Может фаервол блокирует или еще что - не знаю.

Comment: Так и есть, проблема в файрволе скорее всего.